# How to test a function which calls another function when doing unit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

i am doing unit tests for my program, but i got a problem. i don't know how to deal with the situation that function A calls function and i am just going to test function A. it is said that i am supposed to create a stub module to simulate function as stub module. but i just don't know how to do this by `JUnit`.
for example:

```
public class compute
{
    public int multiply(int a,int b)
    {
        return a*b;
    }
    public int cube(int a)
    {
        return(multiply(multiply(a,a),a);
    }
}
```

So, in this case, how to write test code for function `cube()`? how to simulate `multiply()`?

Comment: I'd argue that there is no need to stub or mock anything in this case.

Comment: thank you for your advice, but could you please me in what condition that stubs or mocks are needed and why they are not in need in this case? if i don't use stub so how can i find out the bug if function multiply() does contains error?

Comment: If multiply function has a bug you will get to know it in the test case written for multiply method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably no reason to mock anything here and indeed with your cube() method as it is it is problematic. However you can test the methods of a class in isolation if required by either using a mocking framework such as Mockito to create a partial mock (i.e. mock some methods of a class but call the real code for others)
or simply override the multiply() method in an anonymous class such as below **although you would need to change your code in cube to a * multiply(a, a)**

```
@Test
public void testCube(){
    compute c  = createMock(9);
    Assert.assertTrue(27, c.cube(3));
}

public compute createMock(final int result){
    compute c = new compute(){
        @Override
        public int multiply(int a, int b){
            return result;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a stub/mock here to simulate `multiply` method.

You usually use them when you are calling a method on a different object. For ex, from a service class you are calling a dao class, then you stub/mock the dao class. Said that, as Alan indicated you can always have a partial mock/anonymous class/override to stub/mock only certain functions of a class under test.

Here in your case you just need to test cube method as it is and no need to mock multiply.

Comment: it is also a valid approach to test each method of a class in isolation.

Comment: @AlanHay agree and corrected my statements accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you were desperate to mock this method, this can be done by subclassing this class and providing a mock implementation of the relevant method(s) there.

That said, in this case it's really not necessary as you are not really relying on any third-party objects.  If you later decide to change your implementation of cube to not use the multiply method, you'd have to rewrite your tests.